# Loop in r to create plot of each column and save as png

Tags: r, loops

I am having trouble with *for* looping in R.

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
gender  = c("male", "male", "male","male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female") 
hypotonia = c("yes", "yes","yes","yes", "yes","yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no") 
seizures = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no","no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes") 

df <- data.frame(gender, hypotonia, seizures)
```

Now, I want to create mosaic plots that to show the relationship of gender and hypotonia as well as gender and seizure occurence. I managed a way to create these by hand:

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(~ gender + hypotonia, data = df, shade = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

However, I don't want to create and save each plot individually, but rather loop through a defined list of columns and save each plot as a .png file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What package is the `mosaic()` function from?

Comment: it is the "vcd" package

Answer (score 0):

Below the function `combn` generates the combinations between the different columns in your `data.frame`. Then the for loop goes over those combinations. The `png()` function tells R to plot to a file, see the help for options, there are also other formats available (like `jpeg()`). `as.formula` takes the variable names from the results of `combn` and makes the formula for that combination. Here I call a base `mosaicplot` function but your plotting function should work as well. `dev.off()` is necessary to write the graphics state to the png file.

```
gender  = c("male", "male", "male","male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female") 
hypotonia = c("yes", "yes","yes","yes", "yes","yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no") 
seizures = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no","no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes") 

df <- data.frame(gender, hypotonia, seizures)
col.pairs <- combn(colnames(df), m = 2)
for (i in seq_len(dim(col.pairs)[[2]])) {
  png(paste0(col.pairs[1, i], "-", col.pairs[2, i], ".png"))
  f <- as.formula(paste('~', col.pairs[1, i], '+', col.pairs[2, i]))
  mosaicplot(f, data = df, shade = TRUE)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: `c` is not a great name for a variable...